# NestJS API Authentication

Tags: authentication, jwt, nestjs, openid-connect, openapi

I am creating a API using nestJS. As I am currently working on a "Proof of concept", where I am authenticating the user by verifying their "credentials" (username and password), then the user (developer) get a JWT token back, which the user sends as Bearer token.

Moving forward, I have some concerns using username and password to issue an access token. As I understand the option would be to use an ID provider og some sort. The best would be to use something like Azure Open Id Connect provider (but that means that the users needs to have a Microsoft email account of some sort?). I could even write my own?

So my question is: What would be the recommended solution in order to authenticate the user so I can issue a bearer token?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up middleware "https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware" go through this link.